# Can I use a expression "regular bedtimes" for adult?

Tags: expressions

I have a kind of insomnia so that my sleeping times are unstable.
Can I say

> I don't have regular bedtimes.

Maybe is this expression suitable for child parenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's nothing wrong with it... though you might opt for "I don't have a regular bedtime" if what you mean is that you don't have a time that you go to bed every day.

As an example, if someone goes to bed at midnight every day, midnight is their "regular bedtime" even though it's seven days a week, it's a singular time. If, however, someone has a weekday bedtime at 10 and a weekend bedtime at midnight, you might say they have "regular bedtimes" as they have two different times they go to bed dependent on the day of the week.

Adults can have a "bedtime", though, if that's the crux of your question. It may not be "official" the way a kid's is but it's not uncommon to get into a habit of going to bed at a particular time and calling that your "bedtime".

Comment: I often say "It's past my bedtime", especially the older I get and the time gets earlier and earlier  :(